# Generating Multiple series from multiple indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to generate multiple series from the following dataframe, ideally also plot them on the same figure.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

# setting up data 
ind1 = np.mod(np.arange(0, 3*4), 3)
ind2 = np.mod(np.repeat(np.array([[1,2,3]]), 4), 3)
y = 2*ind1 - 0.5*ind2 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ind1':ind1,'ind2':ind2,'y':y})
df.set_index(['ind1','ind2'], inplace=True)
```

Where the first series, y_1 would be something like y_1 = df.ind1==0, y_2 = df.ind2==1 and so on.

I can imagine long and clunky ways of doing this operation 'manually' but I feel certain there is an elegant one or two liner way of handling this that I'm missing...

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you provide some example result df?

Comment: Hi, what you wrote below demonstrates and covers what I want exactly. I had come up with a similar method but was more clunky. I wonder if it would be possible to do that whole iteration in a one-liner (or if it would even be worth the trouble).

Comment: I don't think it is worth nor readable to create a one liner here because it involves several seperate steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution even though I'm not sure if it fits what you're looking for:

```
# get number of index levels
lvl_cnt = len(df.index.levels)

# iterate each level, and add column to dataframe
for idx in range(lvl_cnt):
    label = "y_{}".format(idx+1)
    values = df.index.get_level_values(idx)
    df[label] = (values == idx).astype(int)

print(df)

                 y     y_1  y_2
ind1    ind2            
0       1      -0.5    1    1
1       1       1.5    0    1
2       1       3.5    0    1
0       1      -0.5    1    1
1       2       1.0    0    0
2       2       3.0    0    0
0       2      -1.0    1    0
1       2       1.0    0    0
2       0       4.0    0    0
0       0       0.0    1    0
1       0       2.0    0    0
2       0       4.0    0    0
```